# file saved path on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I'm new to .NET Core and Azure I have created an API with SQL-Server and I used Dapper for saving the path to the database for POST form-data with an image, like this:

```
private async Task<string> WriteFile(Image image)
{
    String fileName;
    IFormFile file = image.image;
    long Id = image.ShopId;

    try
    {
        var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
        fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extension; 
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\cccc", fileName);

        using (var bits = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(bits);
        }

        Image imageupload = new Image(path,Id);

        toDb(imageupload);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }

    return fileName;
}

public void toDb(Image imageUpload)
{
    string path = imageUpload.path;
    long ShopId = unchecked((int)imageUpload.ShopId);

    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
    {
        string sQuery = "UPDATE shop SET path = @path WHERE ShopId = @ShopId ;"; 

        dbConnection.Open();
        dbConnection.Execute(sQuery, new {path = path,ShopId = ShopId});
    }
}
```

Before I deployed to Azure it returned image path `"F:\\xxxx\\yyyyy\\zzzzzz\\aaaaaa\\wwwroot\\bbbbbb\\5d665cbc-679d-4926-862b-4e10f9358e8a.png"`

After i deployed it return my image path

```
D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\wwwroot\\Shops\\a81c757e-df7e-4cf6-b778-20fc5fcf922d.png
```

can i view image by using this path if it possible how it view;
If the error is my path that file tried to save to how can I fix it? If I changed saved path to `wwwroot\\bbbbbb\\5d665cbc-679d-4926-862b-4e10f9358e8a.png` can I viewed file it from client app if its also not possible. How can i fixed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i view image by using this path if it possible how it view.

Yes, in the Azure WebApp D:\home is shared for us. We could get more information about Azure WebApp Sandbox from this [tutorial](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#file-system-restrictionsconsiderations).

We could use the Kudu(To access your KUDU console, using your DEPLOYMENT credentials, navigate to https://*****.scm.azurewebsites.net where ***** is the name of your Web App.) to view, upload or download the files.

We also could use the FTP tool to download or upload the files to Azure WebApp site.

> can I viewed file it from client app if its also not possible. How can i fixed this?

I recommand that you could store the image information to Azure storge. It is easy for us to access from client side. For more information about how to use Azure Storage, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows).

Comment: Based on my experience, we could use https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs rest api to download the zip file, you could unzip it from client. But I as mentioned that you could use the Azure storage easily to handle that.

Comment: i saved files on Azure Storage and save it path on DB then i will be able to acess it normal way is this correct way

Comment: Yes you could do that. But for the azure blob storage, If you want to get the blob file ,you could set the blob container public or with SAS token to get the file.